# Determine $(a,b)$ and $(c,d).$ Matrix Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B={(1,2),(a,b)}$ and $B'= {(2,1),(c,d)}$ be ordered bases for $\mathbb{R}^2$. If the transition matrix from B to B' is

\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
2 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}

Determine $(a,b)$ and $(c,d).$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried, and where are you having trouble?

Comment: Think about the *definition* of the transition matrix is.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\textsf V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, $\beta = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\beta' = \{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ two basis of $\textsf V$. If we write each vector in $\beta$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $\beta'$, say
$$v_j = a_{1j}w_1 + a_{2j}w_2 + \cdots + a_{nj}w_n \qquad (1\leq j\leq n)$$
then the matrix 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
is called the *change of basis* matrix, or the *transition* matrix between $\beta$ and $\beta'$.